# reading html tags in xml python minidom

Tags: python, xml, minidom

I have some HTML tags in XML files that needs to be parsed in its entirety.

Example: `<String>Click <a href="{0}">here</a> to visit our website.</String>`

Right now, when I am parsing the nodeValue, I am only retrieving "Click"

```
text_value = textelt.nodeValue
```

How could I retrieve everything between `<String>...</String>` ?

Comment: Please provide a short, complete program that demonstrates the error you are having. (I should think a 5-10 line program would be sufficient in this case.) Make sure that the program is complete, so that others can run it. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for more info.

Comment: Consider using http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/